# Gratis windows app to repair MP4

Tags: windows, gratis, mp4

What the title says - I wan a gratis solution to repair a corrupt MP4 file, in Windows 10. The simpler to use, the better.

Please only post an answer that you have personally used and know to work. Thanks

Comment: Could you specify "corrupted"? Not playable at all or sound problems or stops in the middle, etc.

Comment: All of the above (and more). I have a home movie collection which has suffered from bit rot.